# Error converting nvarchar to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, converters, type-conversion

I want to view the session hours of previous 3 months in my SQL (`hrs` column is declared as `nvarchar`), I need to convert the data into float if I want to view the data of last 3 months but I am getting some errors

```
SELECT sum(convert(float, hrs))
FROM companysonvinunitvenue
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

```
SELECT sum(cast(hrs as float))
FROM companysonvinunitvenue
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST (hrs AS NUMERIC(19,4)) AS INT)
FROM companysonvinunitvenue
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST (hrs AS int) AS INT)
FROM companysonvinunitvenue
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '02:00:00  ' to data type int.

I tried these four ways and failed in all of them, how I need to do this?

Comment: If `hrs` denotes **Hours** -- then why on earth is it defined as `nvarchar`?? Fix your flawed design - if it **IS** a numeric value, then it **needs to be STORED** as such, too! And I'd avoid `float` for its imprecision and use `decimal(p,s)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use [date and time data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) for datetime  values. And you will avoid these and many other troubles and also save disk space, RAM, reduce number of reads and so on.

As for your problem. For Sql Server 2008+

```
DECLARE @companysonvinunitvenue TABLE (hrs NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT @companysonvinunitvenue VALUES ('02:00:00'),('21:31:03')

SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,CAST(hrs AS time))
FROM @companysonvinunitvenue
```

For other versions

```
DECLARE @companysonvinunitvenue TABLE (hrs NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT @companysonvinunitvenue VALUES ('02:00:00'),('21:31:03')

SELECT cast(LEFT(hrs,2) AS INT)
FROM @companysonvinunitvenue
```